# select checkbox, previous selected check box will uncheck in excel

Tags: excel, checkbox

I have an excel file that I place a check box as I cannot use the radio button due the check box is linked with formula on excel, in the selection i.e. 1 2 3 4 if I select check box 1, then I select check box 3, check box 1 check should uncheck automatically

[image: Sample Picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question is that you want that, in each row when you mark a checkbox, the others are deactivated automatically.

There are two options:

1. Option 1

This option is the simplest, however, instead of using the checkboxes, the option buttons are used.

1.1 Step 1

Insert a Groupbox, for which you go to: Developer -> Insert -> Group Box (see Figure 1)

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HOVu.png)

1.2 Step 2

Insert an Option Button, for which you go to: Developer -> Insert -> Option Button (see Figure 2)

[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3OOE.png)

1.3 Step 3

Once you add the "Option Buttons", you right click on one of them and press "Format Control" then click on "Control" and assign a destination cell. You only need to do this once as the rest of the “Option Buttons” are configured automatically (see Figure 3).

[Figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIKRx.png)

1.4 Note

When doing this, the destination cell varies with numerical values corresponding to the number of the selected button, which seems to better fit what you are trying to do (see Figure 4).

[Figure 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkSdc.png)

2. Option 2

In this option, simple macros are used to relate the Checkboxes to each other.

2.1 Step 1

Click on Developer -> Record Macro

2.2 Step 2

Right click on Checkbox 1 and press Format Control. Then go to Control and select Checked for Checkbox 1

2.3 Step 3

For Checkbox 2, 3 and 4 the same procedure is repeated, only the Unchecked option is marked

2.4 Step 4

Stop the macro recording and assign the macro to Checkbox 1. Then you must repeat everything mentioned above with Checkbox 2, 3 and 4

An example of this are for the Checkbox 1 and 3 (see Figure 5 and 6)

[Figure 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyBXZ.gif)

[Figure 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjPgk.gif)

The result would be something like this (see Figure 7)

[Figure 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHMKB.gif)

And that's it!, however if you use option 2 remember to save your file as a macro-enabled book

Comment: thank you for your support, In each check box there are formula (TRUE, FALSE) and each check box has a multiplier for each weight that's why i cant use radio button, =SUM(Checkbox1*Weight*1,Checkbox 2*Weight*2,Checkbox 3*Weight*3,Checkbox4*Weight*4) = score

Comment: I understand, then the second option is the one that best suits since it maintains the Boolean values ​​(TRUE, FALSE), therefore your formula would not be altered

Comment: hi... I tried option 2 but I have this error: "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    With Selection
        .Value = xlOff
        .LinkedCell = "$Z$6"
        .Display3DShading = False
    End With
End Sub

Comment: Hello again, the error you are having when making the macro may be due to the fact that it was not recorded correctly. I added in the post a GIF that more clearly shows the procedure to be performed for the execution of option 2.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance ang big help it is working perfectly now now

Comment: Last question. how do I uncheck the box as in start from the beginning where all check box are unchecked?

Comment: The checkboxes at the beginning are empty, because you just put them in, unfortunately if you save the macros for the checkboxes you can't uncheck all of them anymore. To do this you would need to insert a figure (a box, a circle, etc) and then assign it a macro that unchecks all the check boxes. The procedure is the same as the one shown in the GIF, only you must assign the macro to the figure you place on the sheet.